# Hibernate EmptyInterceptor onFlushDirty() is not executing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I want to do Audit for my entity updates. So I have implemented **EmptyInterceptor**.
My **`onFlushDirty()`** method is not executing, but **`afterTransactionCompletion()`** does executes

**I'm using Spring 4.1 and Hibernate 5.0**
**+**
**I have not done any configuration rather than** `@Component` **in configuration file till** `afterTransactionCompletion()` **get executed.**

What I'm missing here ?
Also how to intercept Event `query.executeUpdate()` ?

My Interceptor class is as follows:

```
@Component
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,
            Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        System.out.println("AuditLogInterceptor.onFlushDirty()");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Property Names :-  ");
        for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
            System.out.print(", "+propertyName);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Current State :-  ");
        for (Object current : currentState) {
            System.out.print(", "+ String.valueOf( current ) );
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Previous State :-  ");
        for (Object previous : previousState) {
            System.out.print(", "+ String.valueOf( previous ) );
        }
        return true;
        //return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState,
                //propertyNames, types);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("AuditLogInterceptor.afterTransactionCompletion()");
        super.afterTransactionCompletion(tx);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        System.out.println("AuditLogInterceptor.onSave()");
        System.out.println("Property Names :-  "+Arrays.toString(propertyNames));
        System.out.println("States :-  "+Arrays.toString(state));
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
    @Override
    public void postFlush(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Iterator entities) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("AuditLogInterceptor.postFlush()");
        for ( ; entities.hasNext() ;) {
            System.out.println("-----"+ entities.next().getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        System.out.println();
        super.postFlush(entities);
    }
}
```

**Code In my DAO**

```
@Override
public boolean updateAssignment( Integer workTaskDetailId, short workTaskStatus ) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    boolean isUpdated = false;
    try {
        session = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor( new AuditLogInterceptor() ).openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String COMPLETION_DATE = ""; 
        if( workTaskStatus == 263 )
            COMPLETION_DATE = ", wtd.completionDate = :completionDate "; 
        final String UPDATE_WORKTASKSTATUS = "update WorkTaskDetail wtd set wtd.workTaskStatus = :workTaskStatus "
                                            +COMPLETION_DATE+ "where wtd.workTaskDetailId = :workTaskDetailId ";
        Query query = session.createQuery(UPDATE_WORKTASKSTATUS).setShort("workTaskStatus", workTaskStatus)
                .setInteger("workTaskDetailId", workTaskDetailId);
        if( workTaskStatus == 263 )
            query.setDate("completionDate", new Date() );
        int updateCount = query.executeUpdate();
        if( updateCount > 0 )
            isUpdated = true;
        if( session != null )
            session.flush();
        if( transaction != null && transaction.getStatus().equals(TransactionStatus.ACTIVE) )
            transaction.commit();
    } catch ( Exception exception ) {
        if( transaction != null && transaction.getStatus().equals( TransactionStatus.ACTIVE) )
            transaction.rollback();
        LOGGER.error("Message     :- "+exception.getMessage());
        LOGGER.error("Root Cause  :- "+exception.getCause());
        LOGGER.error("                 ************************************************************");
    } finally {
        if( session != null )
            session.close();
    }
    return isUpdated;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onFlushDirty` method was not called because there was no entity being modified by the currently running Persistence Context.

Only managed entities can generate automatic UPDATE statements. In your case, you are executing a manual SQL UPDATE, which is beyond the scope of Hibernate entity state transitions.

Therefore, you have two choices:

1. Use [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) as there is no need to write a homemade Audit Log on top of Hibernate.
2. Use [Debezium](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-extract-change-data-events-from-mysql-to-kafka-using-debezium/) since the DB already features an Audit Log anyway (a.k.a. WAL, redo log, transaction log).

Comment: How can audit delete record .in insert and update we can use created and updated user but in delete we dont know who delete record